# Local domain being automatically added to DNS records... why?

Tags: dns, cpanel

I'm trying to set up Office365 for my website's DNS through cPanel, but cPanel is adding the local domain to the CNAME (and other) values I'm setting.

eg When I specify the value for the `lyncdiscover` CNAME to be `webdir.online.lync.com` and save it, it gets automatically changed to `webdir.online.lync.com.mydomain.co.nz`

How can I get it to save the correct setting?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `.` character at the end of the value. ie for the given example use value `webdir.online.lync.com.`